# Is mouseup event intentionaly delayed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, mouseup

I'm writing a directive that involves catching a swipe gesture with the mouse, so I'm using a combination of adding and removing mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners. For convenience I add as well a mouseleave listener for when the pointer exits de swiping area.

```
Vue.directive('swipe-scroll', {
  inserted(el, binding) {

    el.scroll = ({ movementX }) => {
      (...)
    };

    el.constrain = () => {
      el.removeEventListener('mousemove', el.scroll);
      el.removeEventListener('mouseleave', el.constrain);
      (...)
    };

    el.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      el.addEventListener('mousemove', el.scroll);
      el.addEventListener('mouseleave', el.constrain);
    });
    
    el.addEventListener('mouseup', el.constrain);
  },
});
```

Apparently it works great, but the `constrain` function takes some time to be executed when being triggered by the `mouseup` event, however the event `mouseleave` triggers the same function and the execution is instantaneous. I don't know if the delay is because the event itself or because the handler execution is delayed by some kind of throttling or debouncing or bubbling up.

Is there any process delaying the execution of the handler when mouseup event is triggered? If so, can it be disabled somehow?

Comment: Do you have some code that removes the mouseup listener or are you possibly adding it a bunch of times to the same element which could cause the slowness.

Comment: In theory the mouseup listener is added once in the `inserted` hook of the directive. I'm editing the question to clarify this point.